# Facebook open graph debugger fails to clean the url's cache

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-debugger

Lately I started to encounter difficulties with clearing my URL caches using facebook debugger.

Fetching new scrape information stopped helping. Reloading new information keeping arriving with the outdated version.

The debugger I'm referring to is : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/.

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating, I have encountered an [article written by google](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6062620?hl=en), which have refered me to two different debuggers: [The Sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing), and the [Open Graph object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/).

Cleaning the cache in them both did the trick. Now all URLs loading correctly to me and anyone I tested the url on his computer (an inconsistency which have appeared till now, but now been resolved).

Good luck!